# Convert quoted number from JSON (swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift, json-deserialization, jsondecoder

I have a struct like bellow:

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
    
    var id: Int?

}
```

and the JSON that i was receiving from server was like this:

```
{
    "id": 12345
}
```

But now server-side decided to send all numbers as quoted numbers like this:

```
{
    "id": "12345"
}
```

When decoding this json using `JSONDecoder().decode` i got an error,

> `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format`

Is there any way, (except writing custom Encodable and Decodable implementation for every struct that i created up to now) to solve this problem? For example doing something on `JSONDecoder()`

Comment: No, you need to convert it manually

Comment: It's not a *quoted number*, it's `String`. Declare `let id: String`. And never `print(error.localizedDescription)`, instead `print(error)`. It tells you the real error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by implementing Decodable protocol's required initializer, init(from:):

```swift
extension MyStruct {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let idString = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        id = Int(idString)
    }
}
```

And don't forget to decode values of other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not uncommon to send numbers as quoted strings in JSON. While it's preferable to request the backend to serialize numbers as JSON numbers, client developers often can't influence backend developers directly. Here are several solutions:

1. Implement `init(from: Decoder)` manually, as suggested in other answers.
2. Use property wrappers, such as `@Quoted var int: Int?`. Remember to extend all decoder container types with `decodeIfPresent` for your property wrapper type.
3. Employ custom `JSONDecoder` implementations.
4. Utilize codable tools for native decoders like [CodableProxies](https://github.com/dankinsoid/CodableProxies), [extensions](https://github.com/DoubleHH/JSONDecoderExtensions), and [MetaCodable](https://github.com/SwiftyLab/MetaCodable), etc.